# Regular expression in jsp

Tags: java

I need a regular expression which accepts both alphanumeric and also alphabets but not numerics alone, and special characters allowed are .(dot) and _(underscore).

Valid entries are

1.ABC123de (alphanumeric- irrespective of the case)
   2.   ABCDEfgh (only alphabets – irrespective of the case)
   3.   Abc_.123 (only special characters allowed are _ and .)

Invalid entry:`666666`(numeric alone)

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[A-Za-z0-9._]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9._]*`

Will match any string with alphanumeric or the two special characters, provided it contains at least one alphabetic character.

Edit: You seem to be discovering a lot of requirements as we go... The pattern below will match a string which starts with a letter or `_`, ends with an letter or digit and consists only of letters, digits, `.` and `_`.
`^[\\p{L}_](?[\\p{L}\\d._]*[\\p{L}\\d])?$`

Comment: Thanks, I tried for 1 day , then you gave me a wonderful solution.Thanks again Jacob

Comment: Glad it seems to work! @downvoter care to explain? If I've made a mistake I'd like to know.

Comment: Hi Jacob,can we make the above expression  accept other language characters like portuguese inaddition to _(underscore) and .(dot).

Comment: @balaji \\p{L} will match _any_ letter, so the regex would be `[\\p{L}\\d._]*\\p{L}+[\\p{L}\\d._]*`. I'm not sure about restricting it to only Portuguese letters though.

Comment: Hi,Yes you are correct, it is not about just restricting to portuguese, I tried with the one you gave, but it is not accepting and I also tried by replacing d with 0-9, even then Im unable to get the solution. As we have [A-Za-z0-9._]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9._]* which is perfectly working, can we make it work for all languages.

Comment: It seems to be working on my end, what is your input? Does it work if you run it in a plain old Java file?

Comment: Hi Jacob, it is working if I give                ^[\\p{L}\\d._]*\\p{L}+[\\p{L}\\d._]*$ like this, I mean I just added ^ at the start and $ at the end. Can we restrict this expression to accept minimum of 3 characters and maximum 15 characters

Comment: @balaji Not easily or efficiently, to my knowledge. The easiest way to do that would be to gather all regex matches and then filter them by length.

Comment: Hi Jacob, currently the above expression is accepting names like       1) balaji_,jacob_ like that , can we restrict that(I mean _ or . should not come in the end) 2)it is accepting names like 4balaji,4jacob, I mean we should not have numeric at the first.I tried that yesterday,Can you help me in restricting the above two conditions, as I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks Jacob,I thought of giving it up actually,without your help this is not possible, sorry Im not that clear with my question, many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

`[0-9a-zA-Z_.]*[a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z_.]*`

It disallows the usage of such strings:

```
.....
____
__._._._
666
666.
666.6
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regular expression :

```
^\w*[a-zA-Z_\.]+\w*$
```